# Image not displayed for ascx control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, html, ascx

I am having problem with displaying a banner image in ascx control. Image is displayed properly in design time under VS 2010, however it is not displayed neither in ASP.NET Development Server nor in IIS 7. I've tried to access this image from web browser and it is displayed so this is not a rights issue I guess.

This problem affects only images this ascx control, when I put the same image on for example Default.aspx page it is displayed properly.

Everything works fine on my client's machine. I am run out of ideas, could you help?

```
<%@ control language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="CustomControls_HeaderWork, App_Web_y1ie2anf" %>
<%@ Register Src="Languages.ascx" TagName="Languages" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<img src="../App_Themes/ThemeBlue/Images/banerA.jpg" />
```

Comment: Looks like you have a resource url issue.  What is the URL to the image, what is the URL when you do a view source of the web-page.  Make those two the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resolving it from the root:

```
<img src="~/App_Themes/ThemeBlue/Images/banerA.jpg" runat="server" />
```

Don't forget the runat attribute.

Comment: Thanks, indeed the `runat` was missing, I do not understand why it works on my client's machine. Perhaps he have a different version of the control...

Comment: Get them to empty their cache and do a full browser refresh?

Comment: Will check out on them in the next meeting, thanks for spotting my mistake.